# Direct admin - custom httpd settings

Tags: httpd.conf

We would like to move our website to new server.

I created subdomain beta.domain.com which is pointing to our new server with direct admin.

In direct admin I have already setup domain.com account and I want that subdomain beta.domain.com is pointing in the same directory as domain.com.

How could I do this with Direct Admin? Where can I write rules like this? (I am new with direct admin)

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName beta.domain.com
DocumentRoot "/home/domain/public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example, if you add `ServerAlias domain.com` to your `VirtualHost` configuration, the content for both beta.domain.com and domain.com will be served from the directory `/home/domain/public_html`.

I'm not familiar with DirectAdmin, but when logging into their demo system at http://www.directadmin.com:2222/ with username demo_admin and password demo, it seems you can make custom changes to a domain's Apache configuration by going to "Custom HTTPD Configurations" under "Extra Features" on the main page, then select the domain in question, type in any extra directives you need, and click on Save.

Something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For others who encounter this, bear in mind that changes made to the domain via the user account will overwrite these custom modifications. At least that's my understanding, I'm new to DA myself.